# What is the negation of the given statement in metric space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, logic, metric-spaces, predicate-logic

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $T:X\to X$ be a mapping.

$\bf{P:}$ "There exists a map $\phi:\Bbb R^+ \to \Bbb R$ such that $\displaystyle d(Tx,Ty)\le \phi(d(x,y))$ for all $x,y\in X$."

> What is the negation of the statement $\bf P$ ?

I think it will be : "There exists $x,y\in X$ such that for all map $\phi:\Bbb R^+ \to \Bbb R$, we have $\displaystyle d(Tx,Ty)> \phi(d(x,y))$".

Am I correct ? If not then what it will be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The negation is

For any map $\phi:\mathbb R^{+} \to \mathbb R$ there exist points $x$ and $y$ with $d(Tx,Ty) >\phi (d(x,y))$.

Answer (score 2):

"For any map $\phi:\Bbb R^+ \to \Bbb R$, there exists $x,y\in X$ with $\displaystyle d(Tx,Ty) >  \phi(d(x,y))$. "

Notice that the $x, y$ for each map can be different.

Comment: Why the "such that"?

Comment: thanks. I was copy and pasting.

Comment: Your 2nd line is more helpfull. So I think in first line starting by "For any map...." instead of "For all map...." will be precise.

Answer (score 1):

It can help to abstract from details in cases like this. **P** has the form

> $\exists \phi\forall x \forall y\ A \leq B$

So its negation is

> $\neg\exists \phi\forall x \forall y\ A \leq B$

Now apply brute force! You know that pushing a negation sign past a quantifier flips the quantifier into its dual: so the negation of **P** is equivalent to

> $\forall \phi\exists x \exists y\ \neg(A \leq B)$

i.e.

> $\forall \phi\exists x \exists y\ A > B$

Exactly as @KaveRamaMurthy said!